# How to automatically mark directories as sources/test sources root based on their name in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA 2016.3.3, is there a way to automatically mark directories as either "sources root" or "test sources root" based on their name?

Intellij will automatically detect and correctly mark directories named "src" and "tst", but I'm using many packages that don't adhere to that naming convention, and instead call them something like "source" or "tests".

Every time I refresh/resync my workspace I have to manually mark each directory.  I would like the ability to tell IntelliJ that "tests" is synonymous with "tst".

Comment: What are you resyncing your workspace with? Are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I'm using an in-house tool to add new packages and then manually resyncing inside Intellij.